# How to avoid `#[global_allocator]` conflicts?

Tags: rust

Suppose I have three crates: `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`.

`Cargo.toml`:

```
[workspace]
members = [
    "foo",
    "bar",
    "baz",
]

[profile.dev]
panic = "abort"

[profile.release]
panic = "abort"
```

`foo/Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "foo"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[lib]
name = "foo"
crate-type = ["staticlib"]

[dependencies]
bar = { path = "../bar", default-features = false }
```

`foo/src/lib.rs`:

```rust
#![no_std]

extern crate bar as _;

use core::alloc::{GlobalAlloc, Layout};

#[global_allocator]
static ALLOCATOR: Allocator = Allocator;

struct Allocator;
unsafe impl GlobalAlloc for Allocator {
    unsafe fn alloc(&self, _: Layout) -> *mut u8 {
        todo!()
    }

    unsafe fn dealloc(&self, _: *mut u8, _: Layout) {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

`bar/Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "bar"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[lib]
name = "bar"

[features]
default = ["heap"]
heap = []
```

`bar/src/lib.rs`:

```rust
#![no_std]
#![feature(alloc_error_handler)]

use core::alloc::GlobalAlloc;
use core::alloc::Layout;

extern crate alloc;

#[cfg(feature = "heap")]
#[global_allocator]
static ALLOCATOR: Allocator = Allocator;

struct Allocator;
unsafe impl GlobalAlloc for Allocator {
    unsafe fn alloc(&self, _: Layout) -> *mut u8 {
        todo!()
    }

    unsafe fn dealloc(&self, _: *mut u8, _: Layout) {
        todo!()
    }
}

#[panic_handler]
fn panic(_: &core::panic::PanicInfo<'_>) -> ! {
    todo!();
}

#[alloc_error_handler]
fn alloc_fail(_: Layout) -> ! {
    todo!();
}
```

`baz/Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "baz"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[lib]
name = "baz"
crate-type = ["staticlib"]

[dependencies]
bar = { path = "../bar" }
```

`baz/src/lib.rs`:

```rust
#![no_std]

extern crate bar as _;
```

Here, `bar` provides the global allocator, and both `foo` and `baz` depend on `bar`. However, `foo` doesn't enable `bar`'s global allocator to use its original allocator, so `foo` depends on `bar` without the default features.

Running `cargo clippy` on each directory (`foo/`, `bar/`, and `baz/`) succeeds. However, running the command on the project root causes an error:

```
%cargo clippy
    Checking bar v0.1.0 (/tmp/tmp.wlBjM4wNFx/bar)
    Checking baz v0.1.0 (/tmp/tmp.wlBjM4wNFx/baz)
    Checking foo v0.1.0 (/tmp/tmp.wlBjM4wNFx/foo)
error: the `#[global_allocator]` in this crate conflicts with global allocator in: bar

error: could not compile `foo` due to previous error
```

Actually, there are no global allocator conflicts as `foo` uses its original global allocator and disables `bar`'s one. How to avoid this error?

#### Versions

```
rustup 1.24.3 (ce5817a94 2021-05-31)
cargo 1.56.0-nightly (b51439fd8 2021-08-09)
rustc 1.56.0-nightly (0035d9dce 2021-08-16)
```

Comment: As far as I know, the global_allocator is applied on the whole program, not a specific crate. So currently it's impossible to have different global_allocators in different crates.

Comment: @CXWorks Yes, there must be only one global allocator per binary. However, I don't intend to build these three creates into one binary. I want to run `cargo clippy` or `cargo fmt` on the project root directory to check or format the whole code of this workspace.

Comment: In my case, I got this error because I forgot to enable a feature (it looks like `features = ["no-entrypoint"]`, but of course, it's specific to that crate). Get a look at the features your dependencies have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is workspace's property. bjorn3 said [on Zulip](https://rust-lang.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/197181-t-libs.2Fwg-allocators/topic/False.20positive.20of.20.23.5Bglobal_allocator.5D.20confliction.20detection.3F/near/251115726):

> If foo, bar and baz are all compiled together, the heap feature will be globally enabled for bar if either foo or baz depends on it. Cargo will take the union of all the features each dependent crate requires and compile dependencies **once** with these features.

So, `bar` is compiled with the `heap` feature because `baz` requires it, its feature is also enabled when `foo` is compiled. Thus, both `foo`'s and `bar`'s global allocators are enabled simultaneously, causing the error.